# How do I copy text from my Phone's inbox to my PC's text editor?

Tags: keyboard, copy-paste, text-editor

I am looking for a way to copy text from my Phone's inbox to my PC's text editor, sort of a shared clipboard. ***My PC's text editor has Ctrl key disabled***. So, is there any way to paste the text from phone?

Comment: Are you looking to do this only once in a while or regularly? For one-off uses I'd just edit a mail on the phone, save it as a draft, then obtain it by logging into the mailbox on PC.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to achieve that using  tools like Clipsync, Uniclip etc. to share clipboards over local area connections.

**Using ClipSync**

**Setup**

You need both the client and server. The advantage of Clipsync is that it is very small in size compared to other tools in this category.

You can get the [ClipSync Android client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.bdwm.clipsync) from playstore  (147K B size) and [ClipSync server (desktop)](http://bdwm.be/cs/ClipSyncServer3.msi) (≈ 900KB size) from the main website.

**Instructions**

- First, you need to install the android app on your mobile device, and a Windows program on your PC.
- After ClipSync is set up, there will be a background service running on all your devices.
  This background service will automatically keep your clipboards synchronized.

  **Copying text from Android to Windows**

Long press any text on your Android device and select **Copy** then paste the text on your PC text editor program  with **Right-click → Paste**.

Client:

[image]

<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Server (notification)

[image]

Credits: [ClipSync: Synchronize your clipboards over LAN](http://bdwm.be/cs/setup.php)